# How to extract specific information from strings

Tags: stata

I have a dataset with the addresses of authors' affiliations. Addresses have differing length. But the information before the first comma is the name of he institution and that after the last comma the country. What I want to do is to extract the country and create a new variable for it.

I tried this code in Stata. It works to extract the name of institutions.

```
generate splitat = strpos(institutions ,",")

generate str80 univ = substr(institutions, 1, splitat - 1)
```

I am wondering whether this code also can be applied to extract the country.
I thought it could check from the end instead from the start?

My dataset looks like the following example:

```
Natl Taiwan Univ, Inst Epidemiol, Taipei 106, Taiwan

Radboud Univ Nijmegen, Inst Water & Wetland Res, Dept Anim Ecol & Ecophysiol, NL-6525 AJ Nijmegen, Netherlands
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a specific function in Stata 14+ to look for the last occurrence of a substring (e.g. a specific character) in a string. See `help string functions` in Stata 14 for documentation of `strrpos()`.

If that is not in your version of Stata, you merely reverse the string, find the substring using the method you already know, and then reverse what you found.

If you are not using the latest version of Stata, it is always a good idea to specify that in questions in any forum that supports Stata questions,

```
clear 
input str244 institutions
"Natl Taiwan Univ, Inst Epidemiol, Taipei 106, Taiwan"
"Radboud Univ Nijmegen, Inst Water & Wetland Res, Dept Anim Ecol & Ecophysiol, NL-6525 AJ Nijmegen, Netherlands"
end 
compress
gen country = substr(institutions, strrpos(institutions, ",") + 1, .) 
local rev strreverse(institutions) 
gen country2 = strreverse(substr(`rev', 1, strpos(`rev', ",") - 1)) 

assert country == country2 

l country  

     +--------------+
     |      country |
     |--------------|
  1. |       Taiwan |
  2. |  Netherlands |
     +--------------+
```

Comment: Those who fancy regular expressions will find that `gen country3 = regexs(1) if regexm(institutions,"^.*,([^,]*)$")` will also do the job.

Comment: thank you. Both of your recommendation are very helpful.